# How to manage Angular resolvers in an ngrx environment

Tags: angular, ngrx

The route is /sim/:id

I am using an Angular resolver to make an HTTP request to `GET /api/sim/{id}` to fetch a single piece of data (the page title) which is used in a layout component. The response is a big JSON object but I only want one single piece of data.

Then in the main component associated with this route I dispatch an ngrx action which triggers an effect which does an identical request `GET /api/sim/{id}` and populates the store with the response.

I then use an ngrx selector to retrieve the data from the store and the view gets populated (FYI the view uses a lot of the response data).

This works fine, but I am making 2 HTTP requests to the same endpoint. How could I best avoid this? I don't need code, just some direction. Thanks.

I am using the latest versions of Angular and ngrx.

Comment: you could set up some kind of cache, or use the Observable operator `throttleTime` : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/throttletime.html

Comment: If I understand correctly: You need that data for the AppComponent to change the title, and some child component to use the rest of the data to be populated? I am right?

Comment: yup thats right :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> TL;DR: Use the data in the resolver.

Well, that's it.

Instead of dispatching an action to trigger an effect to fetch the data and trigger a new action to populate the store.... Have the resolver trigger that last action with the data to populate the store.

Take a look at [this article](https://hackernoon.com/angular-ngrx-resolving-route-data-53f88e0b8a5d) for more ideas.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's another idea: In your provider store the whole information in your router data.

Given that you are using the resolver to store just the `title` property (cuz that's all you need in the parent component) and getting access to ir through `this.router.snapshot.data`: If you store the whole data, you could also get a hold of it from the child component using:

```
this.router.parent.snapshot.data
```

Comment: wow that's an awesome idea :) will read the article - will accept if no better answer comes along

Comment: Look at those... I don't think you are getting better answers than those ;) You already have the data in the resolver. Use it from there. Or use a Service, but a resolver gives the user a better feeling of "page loading".